# Sticky footer overlapping content when content contains floats

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am trying to implement a sticky footer with CSS using this: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html .

I have almost got it working, but when having floats in my content container, I find that the footer will overlap a bit of the content.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="container" id="content-area">
  <div class="module-content" id="mycontent">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="current-page" href="http://localhost/">1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="module-content">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consequat et metus, platea
        posuere adipiscing porttitor dis amet ut. Turpis diam amet,
        mollit commodo. Fusce vestibulum habitant, auctor vel ac
        dui, nulla lacus hac, raesent euismod habitant eros massa
        nulla. Justo dui, facilisis cras. Est ante maecenas
        vehicula, etiam vestibulum mi lorem massa, sed nullam
        suspendisse lectus ante purus gravida, iaculis urna pede
        fermentum. Arcu id ligula arcu, erat vivamus quisque
        quisque, tristique ipsum et. Sociis duis ut, morbi dolor
        duis volutpat lacus viverra, scelerisque sodales sed, vel
        nulla. Elit pede nullam ullamcorper consectetuer ac massa,
        lobortis eget id dictumst et quis, nulla metus. Magnis id
        id suscipit porttitor faucibus, felis commodo risus massa,
        fusce tempus praesent aliquet sit vulputate tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consequat et metus, platea
    posuere adipiscing porttitor dis amet ut. Turpis diam amet,
    mollit commodo. Fusce vestibulum habitant, auctor vel ac dui,
    nulla lacus hac,</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#content-area {
   min-height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
}

.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 985px;
}

#mycontent .menu {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   padding-top: 13px;
   width: 100px;
}

#mycontent .module-content {
   float: left;
   width: 700px;
}

#footer {
   color: red;
   background: black;
   opacity: 0.6;
   height: 70px;
   margin-top: -70px;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
}
```

And a fiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/CfuAg/

And a picture of what's happening
[image]

Why is this happening and what are some ways to fix it? I tried adding a padding of `70px` to `#content-area`, but it pushes the footer down by `70px` and doesn't stick to the buttom of the window anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! `overflow: auto` was assigned to the wrong element (it should be assigned to `.module-content`) and `module-content` should have a `bottom-padding` with a height of the footer:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#content-area {
   min-height: 100%;
      position: relative;
}

.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 985px;
}

#mycontent .menu {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   padding-top: 13px;
   width: 100px;
}

#mycontent .module-content {
   float: left;
   width: 700px;
   overflow: auto;
   padding-bottom: 70px;
}

#footer {
   color: red;
   background: black;
   opacity: 0.6;
   height: 70px;
   margin-top: -70px;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modify your fiddle to make it works the way I understood what you're looking for.

I've remove the `clear: both;` and `margin-top: -70px;` and use instead the `bottom` property which I've set to 0

http://jsfiddle.net/CfuAg/4/

Hope this is what you looked for.

Comment: That seems to be quite close, but the problem is that if I resize the window so that the content can fit, the footer does not stick to the bottom of the viewport, but is pushed downwards, causing the scrollbars to appear.